# how can i find out the uploaded file name in python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

i made simple web server like below.

```
import BaseHTTPServer, os, cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

html = """
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File upload: <input type="file" name="upfile">
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
"""
class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("content-type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(html)

    def do_POST(self):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            query = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
            upfilecontent = query.get('upfile')
            if upfilecontent:
                # i don't know how to get the file name.. so i named it 'tmp.dat'
                fout = file(os.path.join('tmp', 'tmp.dat'), 'wb')
                fout.write (upfilecontent[0])
                fout.close()
        self.do_GET()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), Handler)
    print('web server on 8080..')
    server.serve_forever()
```

In the do_Post method of BaseHTTPRequestHandler, i got the uploaded file data successfully.

But i can't figure out how to get the original name of the uploaded file.
self.rfile.name is just a 'socket'
How can i get the uploaded file name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty broken code you're using there as a starting point (e.g. look at that `global rootnode` where name `rootnode` is used *nowhere* -- clearly half-edited source, and badly at that).

Anyway, what form are you using "client-side" for the `POST`?  How does it set that `upfile` field?

Why aren't you using the normal `FieldStorage` approach, as documented in [Python's docs](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module)?  That way, you could use the `.file` attribute of the appropriate field to get a file-like object to read, or its `.value` attribute to read it all in memory and get it as a string, plus the `.filename` attribute of the field to know the uploaded file's name.  More detailed, though concise, docs on `FieldStorage`, are [here](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/cgi.FieldStorage-class.html).

**Edit**: now that the OP has edited the Q to clarify, I see the problem: `BaseHTTPServer` does **not** set the environment according to the CGI specs, so the `cgi` module isn't very usable with it.  Unfortunately the only simple approach to environment setting is to steal and hack a big piece of code from `CGIHTTPServer.py` (wasn't intented for reuse, whence the need for, sigh, copy and paste coding), e.g....:

```
def populenv(self):
        path = self.path
        dir, rest = '.', 'ciao'

        # find an explicit query string, if present.
        i = rest.rfind('?')
        if i >= 0:
            rest, query = rest[:i], rest[i+1:]
        else:
            query = ''

        # dissect the part after the directory name into a script name &
        # a possible additional path, to be stored in PATH_INFO.
        i = rest.find('/')
        if i >= 0:
            script, rest = rest[:i], rest[i:]
        else:
            script, rest = rest, ''

        # Reference: http://hoohoo.ncsa.uiuc.edu/cgi/env.html
        # XXX Much of the following could be prepared ahead of time!
        env = {}
        env['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = self.version_string()
        env['SERVER_NAME'] = self.server.server_name
        env['GATEWAY_INTERFACE'] = 'CGI/1.1'
        env['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = self.protocol_version
        env['SERVER_PORT'] = str(self.server.server_port)
        env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = self.command
        uqrest = urllib.unquote(rest)
        env['PATH_INFO'] = uqrest
        env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = 'ciao'
        if query:
            env['QUERY_STRING'] = query
        host = self.address_string()
        if host != self.client_address[0]:
            env['REMOTE_HOST'] = host
        env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = self.client_address[0]
        authorization = self.headers.getheader("authorization")
        if authorization:
            authorization = authorization.split()
            if len(authorization) == 2:
                import base64, binascii
                env['AUTH_TYPE'] = authorization[0]
                if authorization[0].lower() == "basic":
                    try:
                        authorization = base64.decodestring(authorization[1])
                    except binascii.Error:
                        pass
                    else:
                        authorization = authorization.split(':')
                        if len(authorization) == 2:
                            env['REMOTE_USER'] = authorization[0]
        # XXX REMOTE_IDENT
        if self.headers.typeheader is None:
            env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = self.headers.type
        else:
            env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = self.headers.typeheader
        length = self.headers.getheader('content-length')
        if length:
            env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = length
        referer = self.headers.getheader('referer')
        if referer:
            env['HTTP_REFERER'] = referer
        accept = []
        for line in self.headers.getallmatchingheaders('accept'):
            if line[:1] in "\t\n\r ":
                accept.append(line.strip())
            else:
                accept = accept + line[7:].split(',')
        env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = ','.join(accept)
        ua = self.headers.getheader('user-agent')
        if ua:
            env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = ua
        co = filter(None, self.headers.getheaders('cookie'))
        if co:
            env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = ', '.join(co)
        # XXX Other HTTP_* headers
        # Since we're setting the env in the parent, provide empty
        # values to override previously set values
        for k in ('QUERY_STRING', 'REMOTE_HOST', 'CONTENT_LENGTH',
                  'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'HTTP_COOKIE', 'HTTP_REFERER'):
            env.setdefault(k, "")
        os.environ.update(env)
```

This could be substantially simplified further, but not without spending some time and energy on that task:-(.

With this `populenv` function at hand, we can recode:

```
def do_POST(self):
    populen(self)
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile)
    upfilecontent = form['upfile'].value
    if upfilecontent:
        fout = open(os.path.join('tmp', form['upfile'].filename), 'wb')
        fout.write(upfilecontent)
        fout.close()
    self.do_GET()
```

...and live happily ever after;-).  (Of course, using any decent WSGI server, or even [the demo one](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server), would be much easier, but this exercise *is* instructive about CGI and its internals;-).

Comment: Thnx Alex. I tried cgi.FieldStorage() in the do_Post() method, but it returns empty class. Should i use CGIHTTPRequestHandler with the separate py file to get the FieldStorage information?

Comment: @tk, you could do that, but there's no reason to put it in a separate `.py` file.  If you edit your Q to show a minimal amount of code that's failing, rather than pointing at that known-to-be-broken example, it's going to be easier for anybody to help you; also **please** edit your Q to show the form you're using to upload, as I already mentioned, since it's totally impossible to guess what problems it might have unless you _show_ it!

Comment: Alex, thanx again. I fixed my question with the python code and the form html.

Answer (score 5):

By using cgi.FieldStorage you can easily extract the filename. Check the example below:

```
def do_POST(self):
    ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
    if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
        form = cgi.FieldStorage( fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST', 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'], })
        filename = form['upfile'].filename
        data = form['upfile'].file.read()
        open("./%s"%filename, "wb").write(data)
    self.do_GET()
```

Comment: in newer Python version you should use `self.headers.get_params()` instead of `self.headers.getheader()`

Answer (score 0):

...or use your own version of cgi.parse_multipart, especially fixing this:

```
    # my fix: prefer 'filename' over 'name' field!
    if 'filename' in params:
        name = params['filename']
        name = os.path.basename(name) # Edge, IE return abs path!
    elif 'name' in params:
        name = params['name']
    else:
        continue
```