# How to properly decode the image from encoded image text from a live ANPR Camera stream?

Tags: python, decode, text-processing, decoding

I have an ANPR HIKVision Parking Camera that detects vehicles and read their details such as Vehicle Registration Number, Vehicle Color, Vehicle Direction and Vehicle Type, and it also takes a snapshot of Vehicle Registration Number Plate. I am unable to decode the image which I get through ANPR Camera.

I have a code written that reads all of the information correctly. For the encoded image data which was coming from the live ANPR stream, I decided to store the data in a text file using the following code:

```
for line in response.iter_lines():
    if line:
        if 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' in str(line):
            with open("vehicle_image.txt", "ab") as f:
                print("Writing Image Text Line to File...")
                f.write(line)
```

It successfully write all of the image data in a `vehicle_image.txt` file. And I wrote another script file to parse and decode the data. The code is below:

```
import re
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def extract_image_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        binary_data = file.read()

    # Find start and end markers
    start_marker = b'Content-Length: 6215'
    end_marker = b'--boundary'

    start_index = binary_data.find(start_marker)
    end_index = binary_data.find(end_marker)

    if start_index == -1 or end_index == -1:
        raise ValueError("Markers not found in the file")

    # Extract image data
    image_data = binary_data[start_index:end_index]

    return image_data

def create_image_from_data(image_data):
    # Create PIL Image object from image data
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
    return image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "vehicle_image.txt"

    try:
        image_data = extract_image_data(file_path)
        image = create_image_from_data(image_data)

        # Save the image as a JPEG file
        image.save("output.jpg")

        print("Image saved as output.jpg")

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
```

Now when I run the above Script file, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000196112225E0>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: [mre] required.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can't the current code I provided be reproduced? I provided complete script which I was using to decode the image text I was receiving. Also I provided the for loop with which I was going through the response. Now, I can't provide my credentials and IP:Port of the camera to where I sent the GET request to get teh response, because that's secret information.

Comment: for one, MREs should include data.

Comment: Well, should I add the url to the text file in my post? Because the text file contains almost 6 thousands of lines which can't be written here.

Comment: is your input a text file, or is your input a picture or several pictures? you tagged [tag:image-processing] and your post contains no actual image processing, which is why I must ask.

Comment: If you look at the code, in the `for` loop, I am storing the encoded image data coming from stream, in a text file.

Comment: how come it's always the same length?

Comment: Its not always the same length. I was just told the length of one of the files in this question.

Comment: [Parse multipart request string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50925083)

Comment: It is not always? But you hardcoded the length in your code: `start_marker = b'Content-Length: 6215'` -- this question is unanswerable, it's not image processing (no attempt to process the image itself, not even a hint that it _should_ happen anywhere, nor was the pictuer given), it's not a [mre] (no data/picture), ... you should [edit] your question and work on it until it's ready for people to take a look at.